# Calling JavaScript from JSF component seems wrong

Tags: javascript, jsf

Calling JavaScript from JSF component as follows seems to be wrong. Can you tell me why?

```
<ui:define name="javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function myFunction( message ){
               alert( message);
            }   

    </script>
</ui:define>

<h:commandButton id="bas" value="bas"
    onclick=" myFunction('call js Function'); " />
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things are "not right":

1. You need to put JS code in its own JS file and use `<script src="js/foo.js"></script>`. JS language namely contains operators which are illegal in XHTML based view technology such as Facelets, e.g. `<`, `>`, `&` and on. You would need to escape them or wrap it in a CDATA block which is plain ugly.
2. If you're on JSF 2.0, you should be using [`<h:outputScript>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) instead of `<ui:define>` with a `<script>`.

   ```
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="foo.js" />
   <h:commandButton id="bas" value="bas" onclick="myFunction('call js Function');" />
   ```